# Adding elements or resources to services (provided or consumed interface) in Enterprise Architect

Tags: service, interface, model, uml, enterprise-architect

I have a meta model in Enterprise Architect. The project folder has one main `<<Component>>` which is the System. This System has many children with stereotype `<<Application>>`. Application means any component which is part of the system. Each of these components have services (provided and/or consumed interfaces).

My question is, I want to add a resource or object to these service. Could somebody guide me how to do this. The only option I can find is to add ports.

Apologies for not providing too much specifics, as the project is non disclosable.

EDIT: I can give an example. Suppose the system is a Car and one of the applications is Navigation System. The Navigation System has a service called Navigation (providedInterface that provides Navigation). I want to add children to this service, like say Notification, Audio Feedback, etc. These objects (or called as resources in my project) have different properties like getCurrentLocation, showRemainingDistance, etc.

Comment: What kind of ressource/object would you like to add? Please describe the purpose in more detail.

Comment: You could use InformationFlow for that. However, it's a complex thing and you should think about putting that info in ActivityParameters.

Comment: what do you mean by 'service'?